# adding image to imagelist from backgroundWorker adding 1st one twice

Tags: c#

Im adding/changing listview items from a backgroundWorker in a class
There is no problem in adding/editing the listview items.
The problem is that in the 1st loop the 1st items picture gets added twice, so each items picture after the 1st one are off by one item, its prob something im doing wrong with the invoke stuff, i have googled and tried other ways to do it, but seem to get the same thing happen.

Functions in WinForm

```
public void _ListViewEditRow(int index, string item_title, params string[] subitem_titles)
{
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
        listView.EditRow(index, item_title, subitem_titles); }));
}

public void _ListViewAddImage(int index, string imgName)
{
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate 
    {
     if (imgName != null && File.Exists(imgName))
    {
        imlSmallIcons.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(imgName));
        //imlLargeIcons.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(imgName));
    }

    this.Invalidate();
    }));
}
```

BackgroundWorker

```
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(delegate (object o, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {
            gIndex = -1;
            foreach (Item gItem in items.Values)
            {
                gIndex++;

                    _receiver._ListViewEditRow(gIndex, gItem.name, gItem.url);

                    string ImageName = @"_cache\" + gItem.name + ".png";

                    if (!File.Exists(ImageName))
                        WebClient.DownloadFile(@gItem.url, ImageName);

                    _receiver._ListViewAddImage(gIndex, ImageName);
                }

                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
        });

        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: That is an interesting phenomenon you have there... If you debug it, what is the sequence of the code execution? I think once you check the code execution sequence you might bet the biggest clue for the bug.

Comment: How do you know the image was added twice? Can you check the contents of `imlSmallIcons` before the call and after? What type is `items` and `items.Values`?

Comment: i know the image is added twice because i have watched it when debugging it, the 1st image is different then 2nd image but the first one is showing up for item 1 and 2, when i debug, as soon as it does each of the functions that are using invoke the debugger seems to jump up a few lines and do it again, im not sure on how invoke is ment to work, but this seems heaps weird.